# How to write the base case in this program about recursion?

Tags: c++

Step 1:  In this experiment you will learn how to declare functions.
      Enter, save, compile and execute the following program in MSVS.   Call the new          directory  “recursionExp1” and the program “recursion1.cpp”.    Answer the questions    below:

```
#include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

      void recursive_countdown(int count)
  {
if (count == 0)
    cout<<"count="<<count<<endl;
else
{
    cout<<"count="<<count<<endl;
    recursive_countdown(--count);
 }
        }


  int main(void)
    {
int count = 10;

recursive_countdown(count);

return 0;
}
```

Question 1: What does the program do?

Question 2: Please write the base case?

Question 3: How many times is “recursive_countdown” called recursively?

Question 4: Please rewrite the program in Step 1 using an iterative function to countdown?  Call the function “iterative_countdown”.

Question 5: Which type of function (recursive or iterative) executes the fastest? Please explain?

Comment: Although homework questions are acceptable, this looks like a "give me the answers" question.

Comment: Sounds like homework -- you should tag it so.  Also, please show what you have done so far and where you are stuck, otherwise you will get many downvotes and no answers...

Comment: "What does the program do?". Well, compile and run it, duh. :)

Comment: "In this experiment you will learn how to declare functions." No...

Comment: We are here to help, on those matters that you cannot understand.  We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Taking the wrong class can be an expensive mistake but not knowing the purpose of taking classes is far worse.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be homework. In order to properly answer it as such, I'm going to guide you to an answer, not give it to you.

A **recursive** algorithm/function will call itself some number of times before it finishes. In order for the recursive stack to stop, it needs to have a case where it does not call itself again, but returns something. This case is called the **base case**.

The program you provided recursively counts down from whatever number is passed to the first `recursive_countdown()` call, in this case `10`. There is a case in your recursive function when the function **does not call itself again**, this is your base case. Think about what this would be logically, when would you want a countdown function to stop going? Now look for it in your code.